# What does Google's cautionary note about Android Services mean?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

In the Android developer [docs on Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) I found this rather cryptic note:

> Note: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21), Google recommends that you use the JobScheduler to execute background services.

As it happens, API 21 is exactly what I'm aiming at, but how seriously should I take this? I think a Bound Service or Started Service is probably most appropriate for my app, so this is concerning. Can a Bound Service be Scheduled? The docs say that a service can be both Bound and Started, but don't include Scheduled.

Am I inviting trouble by not using a Scheduled Service? The idea is to use a background thread to receive buffers of data over Bluetooth Low Energy and make them available to the UI thread. Any special gotchas to creating a Scheduled Service to do this?

An alternative might be an AsyncTask, but it's limited to running only once and I'm concerned about excessive overhead in constantly recreating it to get each buffer of data.

Answer (score 1):

> how seriously should I take this?

The simple interpretation is that they mean that within the confines of the "scheduled" category, use `JobScheduler` if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher. This is as opposed to using something like `AlarmManager`.

The more complex interpretation of their comment takes into account other hints that they have dropped that the concept of "started service" may go away. Frankly, I don't see how they can do this. Regardless, I would not particularly worry about this until there is something more to go on.

> Can a Bound Service be Scheduled?

Technically, a `JobService` is bound to, but it is bound to by the OS, not from other client code of yours. You could try to implement `onBind()` yourself and chain to the superclass for handling certain `Intent` structures (i.e., ones from the OS), but I don't know how well that will work.

> Am I inviting trouble by not using a Scheduled Service?

I am skeptical that any type of service is appropriate. A scheduled service is "I want to get control every hour", which would not seem to fit your use case.

> The idea is to use a background thread to receive buffers of data over Bluetooth Low Energy and make them available to the UI thread.

I am inferring, from your use of the term "UI thread", that you really mean making these buffers available to your UI. If you only need this data while your UI is in the foreground, you do not need a service. If, instead, you want to be collecting buffers while your UI is not in the foreground, then perhaps a service will be warranted.

> An alternative might be an AsyncTask, but it's limited to running only once and I'm concerned about excessive overhead in constantly recreating it to get each buffer of data.

I haven't use the BLE APIs, but I would expect that you need to have a longer-running thread, where the thread blocks on some Bluetooth socket thing waiting for input. An `AsyncTask` is not appropriate, but that does not necessarily imply a service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My app generates real-time graphs of the received data. I would like to be able to, say, open a "Settings" window (would that properly be done with a Fragment?) and make adjustments while data continues to be received in the background. When the Settings window is dismissed, graph updating would resume with the latest data. And even if a Service isn't absolutely required, I'd kind of like to get some experience working with them.

Comment: @RobertLewis: "would that properly be done with a Fragment?" -- a `PreferenceFragment` is fairly likely. Whether you wrap that in its own activity or not would depend on the rest of your UI. "And even if a Service isn't absolutely required" -- it's not. "I'd kind of like to get some experience working with them" -- go right ahead! :-)

Answer (score 0):

JobScheduler is really about having Services started under specific conditions-  for example, based on the type of internet condition, or based on the time.  It handles detecting these conditions and retrying in the future if the conditions aren't correct.  Basically this is meant to provide convenience and correctness to developers-  lots of services end up doing all this on their own-  they write their own alarm manager code, their own network detectors, their own retry logic, etc.  This combines them in one place and provides an easy API to use it.  But its only applicable if you want some event (time, network connectivity, or content observer) to trigger the service.  If you want to run the service now it shouldn't be used.